# Multisite -> XMLRPC

Tags: multisite, xml-rpc

On my site I have Multisite enabled. XMLRPC works on the main site (`www.hostname.com/xmlrpc.php`), but when I try `www.hostname.com/subblog/xmlrpc.php`, it returns a 404 error.

Comment: I just tried it on my Multisite site, and it works fine on example.com/xmlrpc.php and example.com/subsite/xmlrpc.php . Can you please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/166843/edit) and paste in your site's `.htaccess` file? I'm wondering if the redirects aren't set up correctly.

Comment: Hi Pat, thanks for pointing me to right place. The problem was in incorrectly set nginx file. There was missing some rules.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. If you're so inclined, you can answer your own question -- I'd suggest putting in the incorrect configuration, as well as the correction(s) you made. That way, others having the same problem might benefit from your experience.

Comment: Hi Pat, 

all you need to do is properly set NGINX rules following this tutorial - http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx